# Is there a document with all the inflection forms of all the world languages?

Tags: morphology, inflection, resource-request

I'm looking for an overview of all the inflections (such as nominative, ablative, possesive) from all the world languages to get an insight into how the inflection works in language in general. For instance, I've noticed that the "for-form" and the "object-from" are often united even though their meaning in the sentence seems to be quite unlike, so I'd like to know how common this fusion is (and if it's just a matter of history or if there're deeper connection in the two inflection forms).

Could you please link me such free material?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such document however the set of [thematic relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thematic_relation), particularly in its instantiation as ['semantic macroles'](http://linguistics.buffalo.edu/people/faculty/vanvalin/rrg/vanvalin_papers/SemMRsRRG.pdf), may be something like what you're after, but the way that these map on to actual inflections in languages will vary greatly from one to another, rendering comprehensive comparison problematic.

Alternatively, There are comprehensive lists of the *terms* used by linguists in describing the inflectional morphology of the world's languages, such as found in a good dictionary of linguistics, but there will still be gaps as there are so many languages and numerous approaches to describing them.

Even if there was such a list it would not be very helpful for comparison as the same term will have different meanings in different languages. Thus Latin and Warlpiri both have an inflection called 'ablative' reflecting the fact that there is some core commonality between the two inflections, but there will also be substantial differences in the range of meanings/functions of the 'ablative' in each language.